# Iterate over radio buttons and click

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I have this html code which holds radio buttons:

```
<mobileweb-group-toggle _ngcontent-oil-c35="" id="searchType" _nghost-oil-c36="">
   <!---->
   <div _ngcontent-oil-c36="" class="datex-form-field">
      <!----><!---->
      <mat-radio-group _ngcontent-oil-c36="" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-star-inserted ng-touched" role="radiogroup" id="searchType.toggle">
         <!---->
         <mat-radio-button _ngcontent-oil-c36="" class="datex-radiobutton mat-radio-button mat-accent mat-radio-checked ng-star-inserted" tabindex="-1" id="mat-radio-5">
            <label class="mat-radio-label" for="mat-radio-5-input">
               <div class="mat-radio-container">
                  <div class="mat-radio-outer-circle"></div>
                  <div class="mat-radio-inner-circle"></div>
                  <div class="mat-radio-ripple mat-ripple" mat-ripple="">
                     <div class="mat-ripple-element mat-radio-persistent-ripple"></div>
                  </div>
                  <input class="mat-radio-input cdk-visually-hidden" type="radio" id="mat-radio-5-input" tabindex="0" name="mat-radio-group-3">
               </div>
               <div class="mat-radio-label-content"><span style="display:none">&nbsp;</span>Shipment</div>
            </label>
         </mat-radio-button>
         <mat-radio-button _ngcontent-oil-c36="" class="datex-radiobutton mat-radio-button mat-accent ng-star-inserted" tabindex="-1" id="mat-radio-6">
            <label class="mat-radio-label" for="mat-radio-6-input">
               <div class="mat-radio-container">
                  <div class="mat-radio-outer-circle"></div>
                  <div class="mat-radio-inner-circle"></div>
                  <div class="mat-radio-ripple mat-ripple" mat-ripple="">
                     <div class="mat-ripple-element mat-radio-persistent-ripple"></div>
                  </div>
                  <input class="mat-radio-input cdk-visually-hidden" type="radio" id="mat-radio-6-input" tabindex="0" name="mat-radio-group-3">
               </div>
               <div class="mat-radio-label-content"><span style="display:none">&nbsp;</span>Work Order</div>
            </label>
         </mat-radio-button>
      </mat-radio-group>
   </div>
</mobileweb-group-toggle>
```

How I can iterate over the parent node and click on the first or the second node no matter wha tid the ID of the radio buttons?

Comment: What about: `driver.findElements(By.xpath("xpath_of_radio_options"));` this will give you the list with radios, and you can use `Random` to pick one of them and click on it.

Comment: I need to click only on the first or only on the second. Not a random radio button.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you should click on `mat-radio-inner-circle` element inside the `mat-radio-button` block to select that radio button. If so you can do the following:

```java
List<WebElement>list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'datex-radiobutton mat-radio-button')]//div[@class='mat-radio-inner-circle']"));
```

Now, in order to click the first radio button you should perform:

```java
list.get(0).click();
```

In order to click the second radio button

```java
list.get(1).click();
```

etc.
In case the element accepting the click is different - change the XPath accordingly

Comment: Unfortunately I get `org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable: element has zero size`

Comment: Try setting some delay before accessing that element. Looks like you trying to access that element  while it is still not fully rendered.

Comment: How I can add listener into the above code?

Comment: I did not mean listener. Why not just put a sleep of couple of second there? If this resolves the issue - then you can think how to make this more elegant. Normally explicit wait (expected conditions) of element to be visible / clickable is the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

Xpath would be

```
//type[@radio][1] or //type[@radio][2]
```

as you wish.

Comment: Can you extend the answer a little but please?